# Disabling a specific warning in a specific line in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, warnings, suppress-warnings

I'm writing an iPhone app against the Base 4.0 SDK, but I'm targeting OS 3.1.3 so OS 3 users can use the app.

I call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

which is deprecated in iOS 4.0. I'm aware of this, and have measures in place to call the newer "withAnimation" version if we are running under iOS 4.0 or greater.

However, I'm getting a warning that I'm calling a deprecated SDK.

I'd like to disable this specific warning in this specific place. I want all other warnings (including the same deprecated warning in other locations)

Can this be accomplished in Xcode?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

For CLANG, this works:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
  // Here I like to leave a comment to my future self to explain why I need this deprecated call
  NSString *myUDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

You can use it inside a method, which allows you to be very specific about the line that causes the warning you want to have ignored.

Comment: This should really be marked as the correct answer. It's less hacky and solves the issue at compile time, in addition to being a bit cleaner.

Comment: +1 for correct usage of clang, this should be the answer, NSInvocation is a hack

Comment: And also very nice for marking a comment for future self!

Comment: See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) for all warning ignore strings.

Comment: And the list of warnings at clang LLVM: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html

Answer (score 19):

You might be able to use GCC pragmas. This should disable the deprecated warning for the enclosed function.

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"
-(void)foo{
    // As Georg Fritzsche notes below, the pragmas only work outside of functions
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

I don't know if this will work with Clang, but it *should* work with GCC.

Basically, it saves the state of the warnings/errors, disables the deprecated warning, compiles the function, then restores the state of the diagnostics.

Comment: Those pragmas aren't allowed inside functions, they would have to surround some helper function.

Comment: Thanks. This didn't actually work. It looks like the 'push' and 'pop' keywords are not valid, as they generated their own warnings.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`NSInvocation`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000212-1804) to get around the warnings independent of the compiler used:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
SEL sel = @selector(setStatusBarHidden:animated:);
NSMethodSignature *sig = [app methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
BOOL b = YES;
[inv setTarget:app];
[inv setSelector:sel];
[inv setArgument:&b atIndex:2];
[inv setArgument:&b atIndex:3];
[inv invoke];
```

Or in a less error-tolerant way:

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
SEL sel = @selector(setStatusBarHidden:animated:);
IMP imp = [app methodForSelector:sel];
imp(app, sel, YES, YES);
```

Comment: Could the `[NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"v@cc"]` be replaced with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] methodSignatureForSelector:@selector(setStatusBarHidden)]` to make it easier to read?

Comment: or `objc_msgSend(app, sel, YES, YES);`

Comment: I have a similar reason as David Coufal to want to suppress specific warnings. I get the general idea of how I'd apply this solution to my problem but if it would be possible, could I ask if there are any special caveats I need to be aware of when using NSInvocation?I get the impression that this would be very easy to use in the wrong context by accident.

Comment: you really shouldn't `NSInvocation` or any other runtime APIs for this. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(@"your_selector") withObject:arg1 withObject: arg2]` instead

Answer (score 4):

you can perform it like this to overcome the warnings at once

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
(void) methodUsingDeprecatedStuff { //use deprecated stuff }
```

or

Just paste this line before using your deprecated stuffs every time to avoid warnings

#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

this will remove the warnings.

Hope it will help you.