# How to disable warning: Using 'stringWithString' with a literal is redundant?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Some old third party code gives warning:

> Using 'stringWithString' with a literal is redundant

Instead of modifying the source codes, I'd prefer to disable the warning in Xcode. What is the compiler switch to disable this specific warning?

Comment: Why don't you want to modify the source?  The use of stringWithString is hardly ever merited.

Comment: Or, if you refuse to modify the source, perhaps the warning should be left there, to flag this poor practice for future maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning message should tell you the name of the warning. You can then turn that warning off.

```
test.m:4:5: warning: using 'stringWithString:' with a literal is redundant 
      [-Wobjc-redundant-literal-use]
```

so you want to add the flag `-Wno-objc-redundant-literal-use` to the compiler flags for that file or that project.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do that is :

1. Select your target .
2. Go to the compiled sources.
3. Select your .m file and set  flag -w to suppress all the warning of that file .

Comment: That's an extreme. Disabling all warnings is not something he should do.

Comment: @LeoNatan : Ohh yes thats my bad ! is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137414/disabling-a-specific-warning-in-a-specific-line-in-xcode this helpful ?

Comment: But the OP insists on not modifying the source, so only the global flag will work.